# Web Service vs TCP/IP Sockets (Java) + SQL Connections

Tags: java, web-services, sockets, tcp

We are currently are at a stage in our product lifecycle where we are thinking about moving to Web Services.  Our system is written in Java which consists of a number of client and server applications which talk to one another over TCP Sockets and also has in-line SQL to perform data retrieval and updates (yuk! I know) which uses our own SQL Connection class which then uses the java.sql.Connection to connect to a SQL Server database using the Microsoft JDBC driver.

The applications bind to one another using TCP sockets.  They request data from and push data to one another.  Which works perfectly fine.

**Thought**

So we are looking at converting all data access and TCP communication to a web service.

The web service would be designed to run on a companies secure internet site.  The idea would be that users could connect their clients to the web service from home - when they are not on the company network - or at work, when they are.

The client applications would send/recieve the messages to/from the server side applications using the web service.
The client applications would retrieve and update data in the database using the web service.

**Question**

I would just like to know what peoples experience is of doing anything with 2 way communication (request and push) over a web service (if possible) and what the thoughts are about doing this.

Converting the data access to a web service seems straight forward enough - I can forsee some issues with performance where large data sets are retrieved in some parts of the system.

I am looking through various reading materials on the matter as it is a while since I have touched web services (using C# and ASP.NET).  Currently reading "Building Web Services with Java™: Making Sense of XML, SOAP, WSDL, and UDDI".  I must admit I thought web services were always stateless but have just read that they are not!

Thanks,

Andez

Comment: the answer of your question from my post is yes , my post is deleted thats why i am commenting here

Comment: can you contact me on fahad.ryk@hotmail.com

Answer (score 6):

It helps to think of WebServices as being the same as any other web application on the transport layer. It uses HTTP/HTTPS protocols in the same way, it's just that instead of sending HTML, it sends XML according to a predefined format (SOAP). As such:

- It's Request/response oriented
- Can be stateful in the same way as a web-page can be stateful, using sessions (assuming you have a web-service client that supports maintaining session cookies across requests)
- All requests eventually boil down to good old-fashioned servlet endpoints in the server

Keeping these limitations and features in mind, think about your requirements and how they map against each other. If you need true two-way communication (push), then web services are not ideal. They are client/server, request/response oriented. The achieve push, you would have to poll from the client. A possible alternative could be to let both the "server" and the "client" act as web service "servers". That would mean bundling some light-weight servlet engine with the client (like jetty) so the "server" could make web service calls TO the "client". Another way is to look at two-way RMI/IOOP.

Yet another way would be to keep the communication layer as you have it today. There is no inherent gain in refactoring to Web Services just for the sake of using web services. If they don't add any benefit, it's just waste. As you already mentioned yourself, Web Service comes with a load of additional overhead (verbose protocol, servlet engine etc), so it really needs to balance the extra cost and development time with a clear benefit. As the saying goes "if it's not broken, don't fix it". As you say the current solution "works perfectly fine", I would probably not change it. That's just me though.

Comment: will have a look into RMI/IIOP.  The key thing about replacing the Sockets is when the user is not on the network, then they won't have access to a machine or IP address so the more I think about it we definitely need something in place.

Comment: Yeah, that's a valid reason for sure. It's less of a hassle to expose an HTTP server to the outside and you can get SSL without having to build an encryption-layer above your transport layer yourself. You will have to rethink the "push" part of you application though. HTTP is definitely not intended for this purpose.

Comment: I have come across Comet on my travels whilst looking into this.  Seems interesting and there are some good examples of this on http://www.cometd.org/.  This allows the server to push events back to clients.  And also a WS JDBC driver on sourceforge - http://ws-jdbc.sourceforge.net - looks like this is not maintained no more.